# Minimizing Touch Latency in DirectX/OpenGL Applications

Tags: opengl, windows-runtime, touch, directx

I'm working on some applications that are touch-interactive and rendered via OpenGL (probably on top of ANGLE, thus DirectX). Ideally I would like near-instantaneous touch response and this is proving to be quite challenging. I've implemented a touch dragging interface a bunch of different times (first in WebGL then in Python using standard OpenGL and GLEW and then finally using Visual C++ and ANGLE in a normal WinRT app (no XAML)), but I can never come close to matching the responsiveness of the scrolling on the Windows Start Screen.

After doing some research it appears that the start screen is using DirectManipulation libraries. Apparently what this does is takes over control of touch input and then the graphics transforms are handled in a separate thread and rendered using the window compositor itself rather than the application. I verified this by downloading the DirectManipulation samples and they indeed do exhibit the same impressive responsiveness that the start screen does.

I ran some tests where I recorded in slow motion a touch down and then drag in both the DirectManipulation sample and my ANGLE implementation and the you can see the pan occurs roughly 70ms after my finger moves in the DirectManipulation sample and roughly 130ms after my finger moves in the ANGLE implementation (which was the fastest).

In my mind this is probably caused by a combination of things - touch input latency and extra buffering / blitting as the screen is composited on screen. The ANGLE implementation appears to use best practices in using a Flip Mode Present in a swap chain, full screen at native resolution and I'm running an incredibly basic application (basically a square that moves with your finger). This would point to slow touch event delivery. I'm using standard WM_POINTER events and I've disabled touch feedback on the window so I'm at a bit of a loss on how I can squeeze any more responsiveness out of this.

What magic is DirectManipulation doing that enables such low-latency response times to touch events? Is this something I can access from userspace or is the responsiveness a result of high priority scheduling in the compositor?